# How to get rid of the duplicate and also with the large value?

Tags: ruby

My list contains

`User1, 0`

`User2, 50`

`User3, 30`

`User1, 50`

`User3, 68`

How do I get rid of the duplicates, but take the largest value out of them?

Like need to contain this: `User1, 50`, `User2, 50`, `User3, 68` and get rid of `User1, 0` and `User3, 30`

Comment: Is this list contained in an array? A hash?

Comment: This list contained in an array.

Comment: And the pairs are also arrays? like **[[User1,0], [User2,50]...]**?

Comment: Correct, @EddeAlmeida

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do that. Here's are three.

```
arr = [[:User1, 0], [:User2, 50], [:User3, 30], [:User1, 50], [:User3, 68]]
```

**#1 Use [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) **

```
arr.each_with_object({}) { |(u,x),h| h.update(u=>x) { |_,o,n| [o,n].max } }.to_a
  #=> [[:User1, 50], [:User2, 50], [:User3, 68]]
```

This uses the form of `Hash#update` (aka `Hash#merge!`) that uses the block ( `{ |_,o,n| [o,n].max }` to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged. See the doc for the interpretation of the three block variables. The first of those variables (the common key) is not used in the block calculation, so I've represented it with an underscore (which is indeed a local variable).

**#2 Order the elements by the second value (using [Enumerable#sort_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by)) and convert to a hash**

```
arr.sort_by(&:last).to_h
  #=> {:User1=>50, :User3=>68, :User2=>50}
```

We first compute

```
a = arr.sort_by(&:last)
  #=> [[:User1, 0], [:User3, 30], [:User2, 50], [:User1, 50], [:User3, 68]]
```

When using ([Array#to_h](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-to_h)) to convert `a` to a hash, the steps are as follows:

```
h = {}
h[:User1] = 0
h #=> {:User1=>0} 
h[:User3] = 30
h #=> {:User1=>0, :User3=>30} 
h[:User2] = 50
h #=> {:User1=>0, :User3=>30, :User2=>50} 
h[:User1] = 50
h #=> {:User1=>50, :User3=>30, :User2=>50} 
h[:User3] = 68
h #=> {:User1=>50, :User3=>68, :User2=>50}
```

**#3 Use [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by)**

```
arr.group_by(&:first).map { |k,v| [k, v.map(&:last).max] }
  #=> [[:User1, 50], [:User2, 50], [:User3, 68]]
```

The steps are as follows:

```
h = arr.group_by(&:first)
  #=> {:User1=>[[:User1, 0], [:User1, 50]],
  #    :User2=>[[:User2, 50]],
  #    :User3=>[[:User3, 30], [:User3, 68]]}
h.map { |k,v| [k, v.map(&:last).max] }
  #=> [[:User1, 50], [:User2, 50], [:User3, 68]]
```

For the first key-value pair of h that is passed to the block, we have:

```
k,v = [:User1, [[:User1, 0], [:User1, 50]]]
  #=> [:User1, [[:User1, 0], [:User1, 50]]] 
k #=> :User1 
v #=> [[:User1, 0], [:User1, 50]]
```

and the block calculation is:

```
b = v.map(&:last)
  #=> [0, 50]

[k, v.map(&:last).max]
  #=> [:User1, [0, 50].max]
  #=> [:User1, 50]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do this, but I'd probably start by using the [group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) method that Array gets from Enumerable, like so:

```
users = [[user1,0],[user2,50],[user3,30],[user1,50],[user3,68]]
user_hash = users.group_by {|user_array| user_array[0]}
```

This will group all the items that have the same value for their first element, so user_hash will be have a structure such as:

```
{
 user1 => [[user1,0],[user1,50]],
 user2 => [[user2,50]],
 user3 => [[user3,30],[user3,68]]
}
```

From there, you'd want to pick get the highest value from each user. The way the question is worded I'm assuming you want your results back as an array of arrays the way the input was, so, I'd go with with [Enumerable#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) to transform each hash pair, and [Enumerable#max_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by) to pick the one with the largest second element:

```
unique_users = user_hash.map do |user,array_of_arrays|
    array_of_arrays.max_by {|array| array[1]}
end
```

End result, unique_users is `[[user1,50],[user2,50],[user3,68]]`